# curl post from localhost

Tags: php, post, curl, http-headers

I'm trying to simulate http post from FireFox's LiveHTTP Replay by using curl. I believe the remote site has some sort of validation that checks where the request is coming from. If the request is coming from their own domain, then its fine. When i try to run a php curl script, i can see from the Live HTTP header that i'm making a GET request rather than a POST. Besides that, the Host, which is expected to be www.aliexpress.com has automatically changed to localhost.

If i use the Live HTTP Replay, it is working fine. So i copied the header data and tried to implement with curl but to no avail. Eg:

http://www.aliexpress.com/cross-domain/shoppingcart/index.html

```
POST /cross-domain/shoppingcart/index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.aliexpress.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:22.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/22.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Referer: http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Wireless-N-Wifi-Repeater-802-11N-B-G-Network-Router-Range-Expander-300M-2dBi-Antennas-US/701252_523523529.html
Cookie: ali_apache_id=113.210.130.113.1374818286515.884332.4; ali_apache_track=mt=1|ms=|mid=my1023002521; xman_f=NkltWLLI3tebQbeQzQLiNBd2/KPKX0D81t0DghVMEl/frYuA+aVHnWGevMXWTEPqdLRqlKLbExYQkL61WPSt7Tr0LrdqOLLGM8yY5cBFOvY79qV9R5iTGSd44oPoKZruCpupEK9UBNSiOIf7Go1TN1AiM0ArpkHYTZ4rigCwLp5l2IEPYmFC8UzRnLivCFmLxbDuEewB52ulEop1Y9xtdEr88bjnwci1PldcvTxCmVDiOnm6rRfbnVfMAWaSWIkqQrnOEfwq2B4B/OER9K9IH7EHAMadb9IiOdMo3yavyt4DGWquCAq1izTtU8GE2mRmvi+PZ8WmR+PNOM3zYU4eaWM7uEevjmV2S7kTtlElmJGqxaT5RpSLcxiRxxbYJToejY36QxDf0MIIKTaaJTacVg==; aep_history=product_selloffer%5E%0Aproduct_selloffer%09709591781%091035163509%09523523529; __utma=3375712.263559759.1374818300.1375458795.1375606693.4; __utmz=3375712.1374818300.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ali_beacon_id=113.210.130.113.1374818286515.884332.4; cna=+/14CsYcs08CAXGC0nFA22WC; xman_us_f=x_locale=en_US&no_popup_today=n&x_user=MY|dexter|wong|ifm|142465266&last_popup_time=1374818565653; u_info=qunLQLajxN+hFYWqPKiksew8tjAelFSu8cj+oG6e7nY=; intl_common_forever=wWZJ4jwSXakD7oylp5nnW9Nwmq8zgJYiqow0UyNV6PEUhc4f0KJghQ==; CoreID6=n; JSESSIONID=F86BD98D5E0CF42A7BE875F648DFA640; ali_apache_tracktmp=W_signed=Y; acs_usuc_t=acs_rt=9af4ec13bf134eb298193f9ac69395dc; acs_t=/iJST0zcbQeKUIQrTj1tDurMpZLQIdanO+zAZzyDlS+blTn+Rwd4skbiIdbQbEDO; __utmc=3375712; xman_t=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; __utmb=3375712.4.10.1375606693; xman_us_t=x_lid=my1023002521&sign=y&x_user=RmoP5to3fHwR+VNOC9lIAD7BpyTVa0YBflCR3S4eFIU=&need_popup=y
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 93
productId=523523529&standard=&quantity=7&country=MY&company=CPAM&cartfrom=main_store&skuAttr=
```

I've tried to implement the raw header(above) with the following:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource

$fields = array(
                        'productId' => 523523529,
                        'standard' => '',
                        'quantity' => 8,
                        'country' => 'MY',
                        'company' => 'CPAM',
                        'cartfrom' => 'main_store',
                        'skuAttr' => ''
                );

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

echo $fields_string . "<br/>";

$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: www.aliexpress.com",
                                           "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
                                           "Content-length: ". "93",
                                           "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                                           "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
                                           "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
                                           "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"));                                                                        //proceeding with the login.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, urlencode("http://www.aliexpress.com/cross-domain/shoppingcart/index.html"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");

//The encoded url below is referring to the login form for aliexpress.com
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http%3A%2F%2Fwww.aliexpress.com%2Fstore%2Fproduct%2FDual-sim-I9300-S3-MTK6589-quad-core-android-phone-1G-RAM-4G-ROM-4-7-inch%2F901666_1035163509.html%3FpromotionId%3D210526801");//This tells the server where were you directed from.

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);//indicates that this is a new session, i assume this forces the server to assign a new session?
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);//follows the redirection that is supplied by the server
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);//THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT! This one of the most common option that is used because this simply means that
                                               //the response from the server is returned as a string rather than output directly.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, true);//This means to keep sending the login information(username and password) when there is a redirection

$str = curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Regards,
Dexter

Answer (score 0):

try setting `CURLOPT_POST` to true

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);`

Comment: tried that. Same problem. The host is still pointing to localhost and the method is still GET

Answer (score 0):

I think you should modify your code a bit:

- remove the `urlencode` when setting the value of `CURLOPT_URL`
- remove the `Host` and `Content-length` header from `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`
- use `http_build_query` to build your `$fields_string`

For debugging purpose, I set the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to be `true` and var dump the respond.

My working code

```
$fields = array(
                        'productId' => 523523529,
                        'standard' => '',
                        'quantity' => 8,
                        'country' => 'MY',
                        'company' => 'CPAM',
                        'cartfrom' => 'main_store',
                        'skuAttr' => ''
                );

$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

echo $fields_string . "<br/>";

$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
                                           "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                                           "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5",
                                           "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
                                           "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"));                                                                        //proceeding with the login.

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.aliexpress.com/cross-domain/shoppingcart/index.html");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");

//The encoded url below is referring to the login form for aliexpress.com
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.aliexpress.com/store/product/Dual-sim-I9300-S3-MTK6589-quad-core-android-phone-1G-RAM-4G-ROM-4-7-inch/901666_1035163509.html?promotionId=210526801");//This tells the server where were you directed from.

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);//THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT! This one of the most common option that is used because this simply means that
                                               //the response from the server is returned as a string rather than output directly.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, true);//This means to keep sending the login information(username and password) when there is a redirection

$str = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($str);
var_dump(curl_error($ch));

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

And the respond

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 04 Aug 2013 11:51:31 GMT
Server: Apache
P3P: CP="CAO PSA OUR"
Content-Language: en-US
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-XSS-protection: 1;mode=block
Content-Length: 56
Content-Type: plain/text;charset=utf-8
Set-Cookie: ali_apache_id=1.54.42.221.1375617091161.869918.6; path=/; domain=.aliexpress.com; expires=Wed, 30-Nov-2084 01:01:01 GMT
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=6EB1295945C27F8A2F788587D4C0E0A7; Path=/
Set-Cookie: ali_apache_track=; Domain=.aliexpress.com; Expires=Fri, 22-Aug-2081 15:05:38 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: ali_apache_tracktmp=; Domain=.aliexpress.com; Path=/
Set-Cookie: acs_usuc_t=acs_rt=8fdfad47f53b46d489d0a905a5a9fb7c; Domain=.aliexpress.com; Path=/
Set-Cookie: xman_t=ZwO1ZDjGpaou2015+mejeWnS90vHjsN3YIDxbrXYOz/mbbJeIZM3q7Pw6ZGTygK2; Domain=.aliexpress.com; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: acs_t=2nqPb5i+QB7aDai5FXRM12xDJghxP4qjmcwPjwaXQ4SI6eV7eGpxjRGNjukEXuEW; Domain=.aliexpress.com; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: xman_f=MC/MUpjkYCKP+PRcAK43k9eQrTR+PE1rldMoChEUHVVlAUcYwh10BKJ0lxWlsPe4p+pYIPC/Vy4wIHJK8fiy4koUaF68CAolRC6UH7q0nmU5HcqWzgyjnA==; Domain=.aliexpress.com; Expires=Fri, 22-Aug-2081 15:05:38 GMT; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i can get the 200 reponse but my problem is, while using the curl command, the URL is referring to the localhost, which is causing the problem. Once the remote site notice this, it won't proceed with the form submission.

Comment: Just tried another thing. Tried to upload to my online web hosting site and still its not working. The host is still pointing to my own website address. I know that curl will point to the website that is executing it but i thought there is a way to bypass this?Any help please?